# How to pass data onclick event in dynamically created row in table by for loop in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have an array of objects like

```
const array = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}]
```

The HTML snippet is

```
<table id="NameTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I am populating the table from the array data (above given) dynamically.

```
array.foreach(person=> {
$("NameTable tbody").append(`<tr><td>   ${person.name} </td></tr>` )
```

It works properly and data is loaded in table.
Now I want to call a function on row click by passing argument of person
for example. i want this function to be called on row click

```
function call(personObj){
   console.log(personObj)
}
```

Now this function should be called on each row click and only relevant data should be passed to call function. How can I get this through JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use jQuery's `data()` method to store each object as a reference to the `td` you create. You can then retrieve it from the `td` when it's clicked. Something like this:

```js
const array = [{ id: 1, name: 'a'}, { id: 2, name: 'b' }, { id: 3, name: 'c' }]
const $table = $('#NameTable');

array.forEach(person => {
  const $tr = $('<tr />');
  const $nameTd = $('<td />').text(person.name).data('person', person).appendTo($tr);
  $table.find('tbody').append($tr);
});

$table.on('click', 'td', e => { 
  const $td = $(e.currentTarget);
  const personObj = $td.data('person');
  console.log(personObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="NameTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but how this statement should be written, if I have two columns, If also want to show id and name in table,
let $tr = $('<td />').text(person.name).data('person', person).wrap('<tr />').parent();

Comment: @GhiasAli - Then why didn't you ask that in the question?

Comment: @GhiasAli I updated the answer to amend the logic so that it's more simple to create multiple rows in the table. Duplicate the `const $nameTd = ...` line as necessary

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, Thanks got it